# Trouble adding users to database using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to store values to my database. This is the code I use to insert the code from my website:

```
<?php
$ident = $_POST['ident'];
$dato = $_POST['dato'];
$kundensnavn = $_POST['kundensnavn'];
$gsm = $_POST['gsm'];
$fodselsdato = $_POST['fodselsdato'];
$prisplan = $_POST['prisplan'];
$operator = $_POST['operator'];
$portering = $_POST['portering'];
$epost = $_POST['epost'];

    // Database connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','my_username','my_password','id14293554_rw2');
    if($conn->connect_error){
        echo "$conn->connect_error";
        die("Connection Failed : ". $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sales_table(ident_column, date_column, name_column, gsm_column, birthdate_column, pp_column, carrier_column, transfer_column, email_column) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $ident, $dato, $kundensnavn, $gsm, $fodselsdato, $prisplan, $operator, $portering, $epost);
        $execval = $stmt->execute();
        echo $execval;
        echo "Done!";
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

This is my index.html if needed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <h3><center>Reg</center></h3>
    
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Ident" name="ident" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Dato" name="dato" required>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Kundens navn" name="kundensnavn" required>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" placeholder="GSM" name="gsm" required>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Fødselsdato" name="fodselsdato" required>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Prisplan" name="prisplan" required>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Operatør" name="operator" required>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Portering" name="portering" required>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Epost" name="epost" required>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Save</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  
</body>
</html>
```

When I press my "Submit" button, this scripts run, and gives me "Done!", so no errors. But, when I check in my table, there is nothing there, even if I type in all the info needed:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCZ3M.png)

Any tips why it won't work?

EDIT:
This is my db table structure:
[image: Image here]

Comment: does your database "auto commit" ? Even if it does, it doesn't hurt to issue a commit after anyway.

Comment: you may also want to check for errors using errorInfo() after the execute

Comment: @Piyper I'm not sure. I am kinda new to this, so I am trying to learn.

Comment: @Kowno19 Post you db table structure.

Comment: if you are not sure, you could issue a commit anyway $conn->commit(); after the execute;

Comment: oh and I gave you the PDO syntax for getting the error, here is the mysqli syntax:$conn->error

Comment: @Piyper This gave me no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table contain `Integer` column `gsm_column`
But you passing `string` value here:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $ident, $dato, $kundensnavn, $gsm, $fodselsdato, $prisplan, $operator, $portering, $epost); <---------
```

Try to change to this:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssisssss", $ident, $dato, $kundensnavn, $gsm, $fodselsdato, $prisplan, $operator, $portering, $epost);
```

Also i would change the last section

```
if ($stmt->execute()) { 
    // it worked
    echo "Done";
} else {
    // it didn't
    echo "Not inserted";
    //Print error
    echo $stmt->error;
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Tried this now, still not working. Gives me no errors, but when I check in phpMyAdmin, it says: MySQL returned a blank result - that is, no rows. (Questioning took 0.0005 seconds.)

Comment: I tried your new edited answer now, and it gave me error: Not insertedData too long for column 'ident_column' at row 1. I think I did it correct? https://pastebin.com/PkFyHfTW

Comment: Try to change you colums from `varchar(5)` to be just `varchar(255)`. This should helps.

Comment: How do I change it to `varchar()` it looks like I have to typ a value in lenght/set.

Comment: Set it to `255`

Comment: I'll try. Does that mean there are maximum 255 characters? Or does it mean on id it can be max 255? So only 255 rows?

Comment: Yes -  maximum 255 characters, set column `id` to be `AutoIncrement`  and set primary Key

Comment: Looks like it works now, thanks! What happens if the user tried to save `prisplan` column when there are more then 255 characters there?

Comment: Set those columns to LONGTEXT then

Comment: @Kowno19 If my answer helped you do not forget to rate and accept it

Comment: So LONGTEXT instead of 255?

Comment: Yes, i will do that

Comment: @Kowno19 longtext instead of varchar(255)

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but shouldn't I just set all of them longtext, in case it will happen that someone type more then 255 characters?